# Accepted Answer Placement?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign, accepted-answer

Why does the placement of the accepted answer come below other answers with more votes? For all the other SE communities I'm in, the accepted answer always comes first if I am on the "sort by votes" tab. Here's a screenshot for you guys.

[image: accepted answer sorted below top-voted answer]

And here's the link to the question: [I can be copied, and still I'll be me. Who am I?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/57133/i-can-be-copied-and-still-ill-be-me-who-am-i?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's because the user accepted their own answer.

From the [relevant meta FAQ post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/68727):

> If you accept [...] your own answer: There is no reputation awarded and the answer does not float to the top of the list.